# Icon font in swing: font icons not appear in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm making swing application in java, of course, with buttons. I decided to make them via JLabel with icon font for good scalabilty. I tried Font Awesome with labels, and it works fine:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, int.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/fontawesome.ttf")).deriveFont(20f);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 20, 20));
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("\uF144");
label1.setFont(font);
frame.add(label1);
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("\uF1B0");
label2.setFont(font);
frame.add(label2);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image: rendered icons: triangle in circle and paw print]

So, I went to icon fonts generator (Fontello) and chosen desired icons.
I added generated font to my application, changed code and made test run... And I didn't see them: they just didn't appear!

I wrote test code (I made icons with red border to see what happens):

```
final Font[] font = {Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, int.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/fontello.ttf"))};
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 20, 20));
JLabel size = new JLabel("Size: " + font[0].getSize2D());
frame.add(size);
// I have 12 icons in font
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[12];
int j = 0;
// There are codes of those icons
for(char i = '\uE800'; i <= '\uE80B'; i++)
{
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("" + i);
    label1.setFont(font[0]);
    label1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 1));
    label1.setForeground(Color.black);
    frame.add(label1);
    labels[j++] = label1;
}
frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("-1")
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        font[0] = font[0].deriveFont(font[0].getSize2D() - 1);
        size.setText("Size: " + font[0].getSize2D());
        for(JLabel label: labels)
        {
            label.setFont(font[0]);
        }
    }
}));
frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("+1")
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        font[0] = font[0].deriveFont(font[0].getSize2D() + 1);
        size.setText("Size: " + font[0].getSize2D());
        for(JLabel label: labels)
        {
            label.setFont(font[0]);
        }
    }
}));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

And what I see?
Some launches are successful:

[image: test run]

[image: test run]

(Each run I encrease font size)

Some not:

[image: test run]

[image: test run]

As you can see, at size 8 I cant say what happens, **starting** at size 9 - characters for some reason are not painted at all.

WTF? Is this a bug in swing or there problems with font?

Comment: Why are you making your buttons from labels and not from buttons?

Comment: Because I don't need to remove button background painting (as in "-1" "+1" buttons).

Comment: OK, but then they are not really buttons. Anyway, can you provide the resource files needed to reproduce this?

Comment: Sure, it's "masked" button :) There is font: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05254772828174415128

Comment: While we are investigating here, I used GlyphVector (seems this works normal) with JComponent to achieve my goal (it is also "masked" button :).

Comment: _"I tried Font Awesome with labels, and it works fine"_ - If Font Awesome works properly, than another icon font should behave similarly. Java usually produces consistent output; I would try to find differences between the two icon fonts. Also, if you already found a workaround, consider leaving it as an answer for future readers.

Comment: I tested with other TTFs and they work 100% of the time. Something seems to be wrong with your generated font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is not a solution of found problem, but workaround. I wrote own swing component that paints given glyph from given font:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class FontIconGlyphButton extends JComponent
{
    // to avoid wrong glyph codes
    public interface FontIconGlyphCode
    {
        char toCharCode();
    }

    private final Color color;
    private final Color hoverColor;
    private final Color disabledColor;
    private final Font font;

    private GlyphVector vector;
    private Rectangle2D size;
    private FontIconGlyphCode iconCode;
    private boolean hover = false;

    public FontIconGlyphButton(Font font, FontIconGlyphCode iconCode, Color color, Color hoverColor, Color disabledColor)
    {
        this(font, iconCode, color, hoverColor, disabledColor, null);
    }

    public FontIconGlyphButton(Font font, FontIconGlyphCode iconCode, Color color, Color hoverColor, Color disabledColor, ActionListener listener)
    {
        this.font = font;
        this.color = color;
        this.hoverColor = hoverColor;
        this.disabledColor = disabledColor;
        setIconCode(iconCode);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if(listener != null)
                    listener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(e.getSource(), e.getID(), Action.DEFAULT));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                hover = true;
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
            {
                hover = false;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setIconCode(FontIconGlyphCode iconCode)
    {
        this.iconCode = iconCode;
        FontRenderContext context = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
        vector = font.createGlyphVector(context, String.valueOf(iconCode.toCharCode()));
        size = vector.getGlyphMetrics(0).getBounds2D();
        repaint();
    }

    public FontIconGlyphCode getIconCode()
    {
        return iconCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1)
    {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
        g.setColor(isEnabled() ? (hover ? hoverColor : color) : disabledColor);
        g.drawGlyphVector(vector, (float) -size.getX(), (float) -size.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize()
    {
        return size.getBounds().getSize();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return size.getBounds().getSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of MouseEvents from JComponent to use undecorated JButton, an to use ButtonModel from ChangeListener